# Editor Unable to Upload Files in ExpressionEngine 2.2.0

Tags: expressionengine

I recently upgraded from EE 1.6.6 -> 2.2.0.

After the upgrade one of my co-workers that is permissioned as an “Editor” on the site said that she can not longer find the place in the control panel to upload photo files.

I logged in as her and confirmed that the file upload feature is not exposed to her view.

I then logged in as admin and confirmed that “Editors” are allow to upload files (at the botton of the File Upload Permissions page) http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/cp/admin/weblog_administration/file_upload_preferences.html

It definitely says that “yes” Editors can upload files….

What am I missing?  Is there something else I need to enable?  Some config that might have been lost in my 2.2.0 upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

You have probably sorted this by now but if she cannot see the file manager link at all, check that the member group has permission to access this via member groups > edit group > control panel access > can access content: file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the "Upload File" link, which was previous in a green box under the "Submit Entry" button?

If so, this feature is now exposed through a small icon that is optionally enabled per field:

[image: Field preferences]

[image: File upload icon]

Comment: No I'm referring to the whole section of the control panel that manages file uploads.  it's called "File Manager" and it used to be visible to my Editor user, but since upgrading it's no longer an option for the Editor... that where she would go to upload files.

Comment: Are you thinking of the third party add-on called [File Manager](http://loweblog.com/software/file-manager/) maybe? If so, it's not available for EE 2+.

I'd suggest using the native EE file manager (under Content --> File Manager), or checking out the third party add-on [Assets](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets).